# How to omit NA values in the final plot when plotting a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame in R?

Tags: r

I'm creating a map of Pakistan based on availability of satisfactory water supply at a district level.

Since it is difficult to collect reliable data for all districts, I would like for the final map to show whitespace where the column *Condition* is unavailable. My SPDF is named *pak*.

```
tm_shape(pak) + tm_polygons("Condition", palette = "-Reds")
```

Above is the command I am using presently to get the following output. I would essentially like for the grey space to not be plotted at all (not even the borders).

[image: Water Delivery in Pakistan]

Comment: You should explain where the `tm_` functions come from (they're not part of base R). If possible you should try and make examples using data we can all use - in this case you might be able to create a similar problem to yours with one of the data sets included in the R spatial packages and setting some things to NA

Answer (score 1):

This may be as simple as filtering the spatial data frame first, something like replacing part of your code with:

```
tm_shape(pak[!is.na(pak$Condition),]) ....
```

this should not only not plot the missing regions, there won't be a "missing" item in the legend either.

Comment: Hey, I figured out a cleaner way to do it. The new command is:

`tm_shape(pak) + tm_fill("Condition", colorNA = NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this just to show the missing vs. not-missing polygons. You don't really need special packages to match values to colours with the sp plot functions and standar R tools.

```
plot(pak, col = ifelse(!is.na(pak$Condition), "red", "white"))
```